# Abstract class or casting?

Tags: java, casting, abstract-class

I'm trying to figure out whether implementing individual methods of a subclass in an abstract superclass, or casting is the better way to go about the following scenario.
Suppose I have an abstract class `Animal` which has two subclasses, `Dog` and `Cat` and a `Main` class where I save objects of `Dog` and `Cat` in an `Animal` array. The following is how I would go about using methods of the subclasses in a more generalized array.

```
class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Animal[] animalArray = new Animal[2];
        animalArray[0] = new Cat();
        animalArray[1] = new Dog();
        
        for (Animal a : animalArray){
            if (a.getClass().equals(Dog.class){
            ((Dog)a).bark();
            } else {
            ((Cat)a).meow();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However a friend suggested that casting isn't best practice, and that I should define each method in the abstract superclass in the following way:

```
public abstract class Animal{

    public abstract String meow(){
        return null;
    }
    public abstract String bark();
        return null;
    }
}
```

After setting the return values of these methods to `null` I would need to use `@Override` and implement them in the respective subclasses.

Which way is better? I'm afraid the abstract class will be too large and will have methods assigned to subclasses that don't make sense (even if all they do is return `null`). I think by using casting I can make more precise uses of the methods.

Comment: `meow()` and `bark()` shouldn't be defined in the `Animal` class. These methods are specific to `Cat` and `Dog` classes. You should define an abstract method like `public abstract String action() {};` in `Animal` class and `override` it in the sub classes.

Comment: @neha that would be good (and correct, imho) as an answer.

Comment: @neha Ty for your answer! I assume this won't be the case for getter and setter methods though would it? If I had a variable in `Dog` that wasn't in `Cat` but needed getters and setters for that variable, how would I go about implementing this in the superclass?

Comment: @LucasB.Bahadir if you have so many variables that are different maybe inheritance is not the correct way to implement this. Which is hard to tell by your example alone. You were talking about methods that define behavior, not data.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca The subclasses themselves don't have many variables that are different, but if I have say 3 subclasses that all have 1 additional variable that each requires a getter and setter, then I end up having 6 methods in my abstract superclass, where only 2 of which is relevant for any given subclass. Would that not bloat the superclass too much?

Comment: @LucasB.Bahadir I think you should post the variable doubt as a separate question citing an example.

Comment: @neha okay I will do so!

Comment: @LucasB.Bahadir as I was saying, it's a bit hard to give you good suggestions without knowing how your classes are actually designed, but the problem you're presenting smells a bit of bad design to begin with. About the variables, I'd go with the casting, not with defining getters and setters in the abstract class. But again, something smells wrong.

Comment: @neha sorry for tagging, but I've just posted the question again in a hopefully more clear format. I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`meow()` and `bark()` shouldn't be defined in the `Animal` class. These methods are specific to `Cat` and `Dog` classes.
You should define an `abstract` method as shown below, in the `Animal` class and `override` it in the sub classes.

```
public abstract class Animal {
   public abstract String action() {};
}

public class Dog extends Animal {
   @Override
   public String action() {
       //your implementation (bark)
   }
}

public class Cat extends Animal {
   @Override
   public String action() {
      //your implementation (meow)
   }
}
```

Hope it answers your query.